# Sheaves on the finest Grothendieck topology

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

Consider a category $\mathbf C$. To each family $\mathcal F$ of presheaves (that is, functors $\mathbf C^{op}\rightarrow\mathbf{Set}$) we can associate the finest [Grothendieck topology](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+topology) $J$ on $\mathbf C$ such that every presheaf in $\mathcal F$ is a sheaf for the topology $J$. Is there a characterization of the category $\mbox{Sh}(\mathbf C, J)$?

Comment: There are some errors in your question. I presume you mean "canonical Grothendieck topology" in the title and "every representable presheaf" in the body.

Comment: Isn't the finest Grothendieck topology defined for any family of presheaves? I was thinking a family $\mathcal F$ in general

Comment: Though yes, the title was wrong. Now I corrected it