# Sheaves on pushforward topologies?

Tags: sheaf-theory, topos-theory, grothendieck-topologies

Suppose $\mathcal{C}_i$ are sites, $\mathcal{C}$ is a category, and $\mathcal{F}_i:\mathcal{C}_i\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$ are functors. Assign to $\mathcal{C}$ the smallest topology such that all $\mathcal{F}_i$ are continuous (see, e.g., SGA 4, Exposé III, Proposition 3.6). Does it hold that $\mathcal{G}:\mathcal{C}^{\mathrm{op}}\rightarrow\mathbf{Set}$ is a sheaf if and only if every $\mathcal{G}\circ\mathcal{F}_i$ is? This would have nice consequences, e.g. a topology on $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathrm{op}}$ such that $\mathrm{Id}$ is the universal sheaf, describing sheaves completely internally on the category of sites. No reference seems to consider this question, which makes me doubtful.

I'm following the conventions+definitions in SGA and ignoring set-theoretic issues.

Comment: Note: this seems closely related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3918833/sheaves-on-the-finest-grothendieck-topology

Comment: Also more generally: for what full subcategories of Psh(C) is there a topology such that these are precisely the sheaves, i.e. I want to prescribe a category of sheaves? If the subcategory in question contains all representable presheaves, then the pullback of the canonical topology under the Yoneda embedding is the only candidate topology, but this is all I've got.

Comment: Aside from your actual question, you might want to look at the _object classifier_, which is a topos $\mathcal{E}$ such that the category of geometric morphisms $\mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{E}$ is equivalent to $\mathcal{X}$, for any Grothendieck topos $\mathcal{X}$.

Comment: @ZhenLin Sadly, this seems to go the wrong way; what I am looking for is more akin to the existence of a representative of the covariant functor $\mathcal{X}\mapsto\mathcal{X}$, $f\mapsto f_*$ from topoi to categories, rather than a representative of the contravariant functor $f\mapsto f^*$.

Comment: After stewing on this, I'm pretty certain the answer to the second question is: topologies are in inclusion-reversing bijection with subcategories $\mathcal{S}\subseteq\operatorname{PSh}(\mathcal{C})$ which are Grothendieck topoi and such that the inclusion is a right adjoint to a localization with $f^*f_*:\mathcal{S}\rightarrow\mathcal{S}$ the identity (where I mean subcategories up to essential image, of course, and some of this is probably redundant). Any reference would be appreciated. This should make the original question fairly easy to think about, though I need to take a break.

Comment: This idea seems very implicit in SGA 4, Exposé IV, Section 9.1, but I don't see it explicitly laid out anywhere.

Comment: The claim I give about topologies is basically given by the equivalence in the topos PSh(C) between Lawvere-Tierney topologies, Grothendieck topologies, and subtopoi. See, e.g, the nLab articles on subtopoi and Lawvere-Tierney topologies.